# Sending data from serialport to socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, arduino

I'm willing to do a simple dialogue between my Arduino and a web interface.
I've been able to do this in the command line so now I'm trying to do the same with some buttons.

I've been using socket.io to manage the sockets and I can emit a socket to Arduino but when I try to emit a socket from Arduino to the server it doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code.

server.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io');
var url = require("url"); 
var SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort;

var socketServer;
var serialport;
var portName = '/dev/ttyACM0'; //change this to your Arduino port
var sendData = "";

function startServer(route,handle,debug) {
    function onRequest(request, response) {
      var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname; 
      console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received");
      var content = route(handle,pathname,response,request,debug);
    }
    var httpServer = http.createServer(onRequest).listen(1337, function(){
        console.log("Listening at: http://localhost:1337");
    });
    initSocketIO(httpServer,debug);
}

function initSocketIO(httpServer,debug) {
    socketServer = io.listen(httpServer);
    if(debug == false) socketServer.set('log level', 1);
    socketServer.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log("Connected");
        socket.emit('onconnection', {msg:sendData});    
        socket.on('buttonval', function(data) {
            console.log('A letter ' + data + ' was sent');
            serialport.write(data);
        });
        socket.on('update', function(data) {
            console.log('Yaaaaayaaa');
            socket.emit('updateData',{msg:data.buffer});
        });
        socket.on('error', function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
        serialListener(debug, socket);
    });
}

// Listen to serial port
function serialListener(debug, socket) {
    var receivedData = "";
    serialport = new SerialPort(portName, {
         baudrate: 9600,
         dataBits: 8,
         parity: 'none',
         stopBits: 1,
         flowControl: false
    });

    serialport.on('open', function(){
        var buffer = "";
        serialport.on('data', function(data){
            var match = /\r|\n/.exec(data);
            if (match) {
                buffer += data;
                console.log("%s", buffer); 
                sendData = buffer;
                socket.emit('update', {msg:buffer});
                buffer = "";
            } else buffer += data;
        });
    });
}

exports.start = startServer;
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
   <head>    
    <style>
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
    var iosocket;
    function initSocketIO() {
        iosocket = io.connect();
        iosocket.on('onconnection', function(value) {
            initButton();
            //recieve changed values by other client from server
            iosocket.on('updateData', function (recievedData) {
                alert(recievedData.msg);
                $("#result").html(recievedData.msg);
            });
        });
    }

    function initButton(){$( "#check" ).button();}
    window.onload = function() {initSocketIO();};   
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#check').click(function() {
        iosocket.emit('buttonval', 'S');
     });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="rData">
    <h2>Data from Arduino</h2>
    <div id="result"></div>
   </div>
    <input type="button" id="check" value="Measure"/></div>
   </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

arduino.ino:

```
float rP = 0;
float lP = 0;
float cP = 0; 

void initMeasurement() {
    Serial.println("Ready for measures");
}

void doMeasure() {
  rP = 0.1;
  lP = 0.2;
  cP = 0.35;
}

boolean start = false;

void setup() {
  // initialize serial:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // init something
  initMeasurement();

}

void loop() {
   // Recieve data from Node and write it to a String
  if (Serial.available() && !start) {
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    if(inChar == 'S'){ // end character for led
     start = true;
    }
  } else if (start) {
    Serial.println("Measuring...");
    doMeasure();
    Serial.println("Results are:");
    Serial.print("Rp = ");
    Serial.println(rP);
    Serial.print("Lp = ");
    Serial.println(lP);
    Serial.print("Cp = ");
    Serial.println(cP);
    start = false;
    Serial.println("Ready again");
  }  
  //delay(50); // give the Arduino some breathing room.
}
```